# The World-Eater's Eyrie - Broken Ring Puzzle Door with Diamond Claw in Skuldafn Temple

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have browsed all of the google hoping to find an answer to my problem.
I am in Skuldafn Temple, and I'm having the same problem others seem to have had with the ring puzzle door.

Initially, the rings wouldn't move at all. I went back one loading screen and returned to fix it.
Now, the pattern is correct, but the key does not open the door.

- I have exited the entire dungeon and re-entered
- I have made sure the left (unnecessary) door/gate is closed on the first pillar puzzle.
- I have saved and reloaded.
- I have gone to the Xbox dash, powered off, etc, the console.
- I have tried several erroneous arrangements.
- I have cleared my cache, some old saves, and the system cache.

And I'm unable to climb the mountain. I tried for a half hour, and after making no progress I gave up.

Comment: Do you have an old save from before you entered the dungeon initially? Does that fix the bug for you?

Comment: I wasn't paying attention (blind with rage), and when I decided to give up and go to my last save from four hours ago, I wrote over it.

Comment: When you try the erroneous arrangements do you get any penalty (poison darts, fire jets etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

same thing happened to me, the solution for me was reloading a previous save before I tried the door, exiting the dungeon and then re-entering and trying this again.